# XPath - get attribute "href"

Tags: html, xpath, lxml

how can I get the "href" attribute from html using XPath?

```
<td>
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
       <p>SERVER-45472</p>
    </a>
</td>
```

Why for me works only this command of "`//a/@href`" ?
Why can't I use this query - "`/td//a/@href`"?

What am I trying to do:

```
from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring('<td><a href="https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-45472"><p>SERVER-45472</p></a></td>')

a = tree.xpath('/td//a/@href')
print(a)
```

After running the script, an empty list is returned to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a part of a HTML file is not a valid HTML document.

See:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import html
>>> tree = html.fromstring('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"><html>  <body><td><a href="https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-45472"><p>SERVER-45472</p></a></td></body></html>')
>>> a = tree.xpath('/html/body/td//a/@href')
>>> print(a)
['https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-45472']
>>>
```

Comment: Kind of `PEBKAC` issue ? :D

Answer (score 1):

Like this XPath :

```
string(//a/@href)
http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Your XPath partially works for me with [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint):

```
xmllint --xpath '/td//a/@href' file
href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"
```

Which tools are you using, and what is your expected output, and what you get instead ?

Comment: I need the full path. The piece of html code I inserted is just a small part. Actually I need to get links from a large table

Comment: So provide a better sample input, even if it's not exactly the same. We even don't know which tools are you using and expected output

Comment: I am used lxml module for Python

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm sorry! I fixed it